# I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo x220 then upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 blank screen

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo x220 then upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 now I get a blank screen after I see the ubuntu logo and the four dots below it. I see my wireless indicator lit as well as my bluetooth indicator lit. Nothing else. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix your issue, if it were me, I'd do a clean install. I suggest never "upgrading" to newer releases. Always just save your data to storage device and do a clean install of the new release, you'll have better luck that way. This is just an observation based on personal experience. And personally, I only go from LTS version to LTS version, I no longer do the in-between versions. I'm running 12.04 on this machine until the next LTS version comes out.

Comment: his answer will not work for you because I ve done a clean install 3 times and still have this issue,its a major hella issue and I ve tried everything seems the makers are lost to me

Comment: Philip I appreciate the response. I do have one caveat: I have files I would like to keep pictures and documents. I booted from the usb and I'm seeing the "home" folder but I cannot access the files therein. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try booting in with a live cd or usb and sudo cp ~/Home* /dev/"your usb dev name" sdb?    I'm a little weak on some of this because I've generally backed up everything that I need. Incidentally, sometimes hardware issues can look like software issues. A failing hard disk can do some odd things. Someone more experienced should help you with those files, I don't know how else you'd get them without being able to log in

Comment: Just a hint, unless there is something special in 12.10 that you want, you're better off with 12.04 if it works well on your system. I believe the next LTS version is due in 04/2014, but the 12.04 is supported until 2015 while the 12.10 is not. A newer version isn't always better, sometimes it's just better supported.